# MongoDB Query aggreate/group by and geometry/location/geoNear query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to fetch the documents with geometry within a certain location, however only want to return a single document per UUID. For this project, in most cases, there are many documents for each UUID that match the $near selector, hence we get many documents with the same UUID.

Can anyone assist with completing the below query so it only returns a single document per uuid (most recent "date")?

```
db.device.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Here's an example of the collection:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a4f1ff0fc6ded723265e6b0"),
   "uuid":"user1",
   "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:29.000",
   "location":{  
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates":[   
            //remove for demo sake
      ]
   }
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a62a245ce689f68245450a7"),
   "uuid":"user2",
   "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:07.000",
   "location":{  
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates":[   
            //remove for demo sake
      ]
   }
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a62a20fce689f7a14648c62"),
   "uuid":"user1",
   "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:39.000",
   "location":{  
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates":[   
            //remove for demo sake
      ]
   }
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a62a205ce689f7039203923"),
   "uuid":"user1",
   "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:49.000",
   "location":{  
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates":[   
            //remove for demo sake
      ]
   }
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a62a277ce689f703a3eacb3"),
   "uuid":"user2",
   "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:59.000",
   "location":{  
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates":[   
            //remove for demo sake
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing this kind of `heavier` operations, you can switch to using an `aggregation` pipeline.

Using this input:

```
{  
  "uuid": "user1",
  "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:29.000",
  "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":[-0.17818, 51.15609] }
},
{  
  "uuid": "user2",
  "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:07.000",
  "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":[2.35944, 48.72528] }
},
{
  "uuid": "user1",
  "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:39.000",
  "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [1.45414, 43.61132] }
},
{
  "uuid": "user1",
  "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:49.000",
  "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":[-6.24889, 53.33306] }
},
{  
  "uuid": "user2",
  "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:59.000",
  "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":[-3.68248, 40.47184] }
}
```

Using this index:

```
db.device.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

This pipeline should perform what you want:

```
db.device.aggregate([
     { $match: { location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ -0.17818, 51.15609 ], 0.1232135647961246 ] } } } },
     { $sort: { "date": -1 } },
     { $group: { _id: { uuid: "$uuid" }, users: { $push: { "uuid": "$uuid", "date": "$date", "location": "$location" } } } },
     { $project: { user: { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0] } } }
  ])
```

I first adapted the `find/$near` operator to an aggregation equivalent ([$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/)/[$centerSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/)). It matches locations within 0.123 radians (488 kms (0.123*3963.2)).

I then directly sort by date, this way when documents will then be grouped by user, I will be able to easily select the first per user.

I then group by user.

And finally for each user, as I have a value produced by `$group` which is an array of the user documents (sorted), I just extract the first item of the array with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

This produces:

```
{
  "_id" : { "uuid" : "user2" },
  "user": {
    "uuid": "user2",
    "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:07.000",
    "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.35944, 48.72528 ] }
  }
}
{
  "_id": { "uuid" : "user1" },
  "user": {
    "uuid": "user1",
    "date": "2018-01-20 11:58:49.000",
    "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -6.24889, 53.33306 ] }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Xavier, worked a treat, awesome answer, your a good man.